# Elasticsearch Id Inference 5.x

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

I'm configuring the `ConnectionSettings` object like so:

```
ConnectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(settings.EndPointUrl)
    .DefaultIndex("myindex")
    .BasicAuthentication(settings.Username, settings.Password)
    .PrettyJson()
    .InferMappingFor<MyObject>(l => l
        .IdProperty(p => p.UserId)
    );
```

When I index `MyObject`, it is not honoring the `InferMappingFor` setting. I've had to index single objects like so, explicitly setting the `Id` field:

```
var response = Elasticsearch.Client.Index(model, i => i
    .Id(model.UserId)
);
```

Any idea why `InferMappingFor` isn't working? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure `Elasticsearch.Client` uses `ConnectionSettings` defined above? Do you use NEST 5.x?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `InferMapping` you should use attribute decorations on your `MyObject` class.  Example:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "myObject", Id=nameof(MyObject.UserID)]
public class MyObject {
   public String UserID {get;set;}

   //more properties
}
```

Comment: I don't have the ability to do that. We have our models in a separate project and don't want that project to have a dependency on ES as the dependency on ES will propagate to any other project that references our models project.

Comment: I know this doesn't really answer your question, but make sure you're thinking about if that model is in the right project.  That model should be owned by ElasticSearch, not shared as the domain model.  You're right not to want ES dependencies in other projects.